# django-tables2 Adding template column, which content depends on condition

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Working with

- Django framework
- django-tables2

I have a table for which I add 2  additional template columns (buttons).
I want to display only these buttons depending on the condition on other column.
Lets say grade is G2 then edit/delete buttons are visible or active. Else they are not displayed or disabled. 
Here it how it looks now:

[image]

Is it possible to do that in table class? Or do I need to write some fancy jquery code?

Here is my tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    T1     = '<button type="button" class="btn js-update" update-link="{{ record.get_absolute_url_update }}">update</button>'
    T2     = '<button type="button" class="btn js-delete" delete-link="{{ record.get_absolute_url_delete }}">delete</button>'
    edit   = tables.TemplateColumn(T1)
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn(T2)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields        = ('name','surname','city','grade',)
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try like this:

First Override `TemplateColumn`'s render method:

```
class CustomTemplateColumn(tables.TemplateColumn):
    def render(self, record, table, value, bound_column, **kwargs):
         if record.grade == "G2":
             return ''
         return super(CustomTemplateColumn, self).render(record, table, value, bound_column, **kwargs)
```

Then use it in the `Table` class:

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    T1     = '<button type="button" class="btn js-update" update-link="{{ record.get_absolute_url_update }}">update</button>'
    T2     = '<button type="button" class="btn js-delete" delete-link="{{ record.get_absolute_url_delete }}">delete</button>'
    edit   = CustomTemplateColumn(T1)
    delete = CustomTemplateColumn(T2)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields        = ('name','surname','city','grade',)
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

Comment: Yes it works. Also I had to make str(record.grade) == 'G2' to be able to compare.

Comment: what if I want to put something let's say a link for example if the `record.grade == "G2"` ...what should I replace the `return ''` with? @ruddra